# Simplify & Optimize PHP Array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am working on combining the array into a key with the count of repeated "option""code". My Request JSON is like this

```
[{
    "productId": "DENSUS-MARK",
    "options": [
        {
            "code": "HIGLIGT_OPTION_HANDLE"
        },
        {
            "code": "HIGLIGT_OPTION_HANDLE1"
        }
        
        
    ]
},
{
    "productId": "DENSUS-MARK",
    "options": [
        {
            "code": "HIGLIGT_OPTION_HANDLE"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "productId": "DENSUS-MARK-II",
    "options": [
        {
            "code": "HIGLIGT_OPTION_HANDLE"
        }
    ]
}]
```

After combing the "productID" and the count of ["options"]["code"] (For ProductId - DENSUS-MARK, the code "HIGLIGT_OPTION_HANDLE" count is 2. So I am getting a output like this.

```
 {
    "productId": "DENSUS-MARK",
    "options": [
        {
            "code": "HIGLIGT_OPTION_HANDLE",
            "count": 2
        },
                    {
            "code": "HIGLIGT_OPTION_HANDLE1",
            "count": 1
        }
    ]
},
    {
    "productId": "DENSUS-MARK-II",
    "options": [
        {
            "code": "HIGLIGT_OPTION_HANDLE",
            "count": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

}

This is my current php code and I need to optimize & simply this below code

```
    $datas = json_decode($arr,true);
    $formattedData = [];
    foreach ($datas as $f) {
        foreach ($f['options'] as $option) {
            $formattedData[$f['productID']]['productID'] = $f['productID'];
            $formattedData[$f['productID']]['options']['code'][$option['code']][] = $option['code'];
        }
    }

    foreach ($formattedData as &$data) {
    $formattedOptions = [];
    foreach ($data['options']['code'] as $key => $codes) {
        $formattedOptions[] = [
            'code' => $key,
            'count' => count($codes)
        ];
    }
    $data = $formattedOptions;
    }

    print_r($formattedData);
```

Someone, could you please help me in this.

Comment: what do you mean by optimize or simplify? are you facing any errors or is this simply a school assignment?

Comment: @Mashtan I didn't face any issue. I want to optimize the foreach loop.

Comment: The core question is why do you need to optimize, and what characteristic do you need to optimize? Speed? memory? Often you can get more of one at the expense of the other. As far as simplify goes, you've done a pretty good job keeping things clear. It's likely that you could crunch things down into a single loop, but unless you have a specific reason to do so, I'd sacrifice potential CPU milliseconds for real Engineer Hours, and move on to the next task.

Comment: @Jerry I want to do this a single loop instead of using multiple foreach loops.

Comment: Why? Have you measured the performance of this code and found it insufficient? Is there a reason you think a single loop would be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the optimization you want. Meanwhile, less than two loops, I have not found. It's not quite the expected result, but you should be able to fix it if you need to.

With:

```
$input = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'productId' => 'DENSUS-MARK',
    'options' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'code' => 'HIGLIGT_OPTION_HANDLE',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'code' => 'HIGLIGT_OPTION_HANDLE1',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'productId' => 'DENSUS-MARK',
    'options' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'code' => 'HIGLIGT_OPTION_HANDLE',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'productId' => 'DENSUS-MARK-II',
    'options' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'code' => 'HIGLIGT_OPTION_HANDLE',
      ),
    ),
  )
);
```

Then just:

```
$result = [];
foreach($input as $row) {
    foreach($row['options'] as $value) {
        $result[$row['productId']][$value['code']] ??=0;
        $result[$row['productId']][$value['code']] += count($value);
  }
}
var_export($result);
```

Results:

```
array (
  'DENSUS-MARK' => 
  array (
    'HIGLIGT_OPTION_HANDLE' => 2,
    'HIGLIGT_OPTION_HANDLE1' => 1,
  ),
  'DENSUS-MARK-II' => 
  array (
    'HIGLIGT_OPTION_HANDLE' => 1,
  ),
)
```

Comment: @GenImpact, does this answer your question?